# Processing multiple arrays simultaneously in ruby

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I have an array : a=[[1,2],[3]]
and b=[[2,3],[5]]
i need to add corresponding elements in each array simultaneously in order to obtain the result;

result=[[3,5],[8]].

Thanks and Cheers!

Comment: If you meant threading then I think this question is similar in some sense to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687362/should-i-use-multiple-threads-in-this-situation-ruby/2687523

Comment: result=[[3,5],[8]] or result=[[3,6],[8]] ?

Comment: its [[3,5],[8]] .My bad.

Comment: You keep asking questions about how to work with arrays that have parallel structures. In general (there are no doubt exceptions), this is a difficult way to work with complex data. I would encourage you to think about how you can bundle all related information together (that's one of the central idea behind OO programming), rather than trying to maintain parallel array structures.

Comment: Well,I do use hashes but there are times when it is inevitable and i have to use parallel structures.If you don't mind please do suggest other data structures I could use.Thank You !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a=[[1,2],[3]]
b=[[2,3],[5]]

def my_add a1, a2
  a1.zip(a2).map{|s1, s2|
    s1.is_a?(Array) ? my_add(s1, s2) : s1 + s2
  }
end

p my_add a, b
#=>[[3, 5], [8]]
```

But you have to be careful to always match an array with an array, and integer with an integer.